# Current system datetime syntax in VB6.0 which is equivalent to sql datetime

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, vb6

```
brdSrNo = txt_Board_SrNo.Text
usrname = txt_User_Name.Text
ndate = Format$(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
voltMeas1 = txt_VoltMes.Text

rs.Open "insert into duct_test values(" & brdSrNo & ",'" & ndate & "'," & usrname & ", " & voltMeas1 & ")", con, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
 'here I get the error'
```

I tried the above code but the error appears as:Incorrect syntax near','. Is there anyway to get the datetime like this:2015-10-30 17:09:22.000, as we get in sql

thanks @nabuchodonossor & @Fred, I got the Datetime pblm fixed. Now I got another error.. where, if voltMeas1=12.5 r something that takes an voltage measure... the error shows : "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to datatype numeric" ,In the sql table VoltageMeasure data type is Numeric(2,2).. can u suggest anthying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use the server time:

instead of:

```
rs.Open "insert into duct_test values(" & brdSrNo & ",'" & ndate & "'," & usrname & ",
```

you can write:

```
rs.Open "insert into duct_test values(" & brdSrNo & ", GETDATE(), " & usrname & ",
```

and implement the changes of mentioned by Fred

Comment: thanks @nabuchodonossor I got the Datetime pblm fixed. Now I got another error.. where, if voltMeas1=12.5 r something that takes an voltage measure... the error shows : "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to datatype numeric" ,In the sql table VoltageMeasure data type is Numeric(2,2).. can u suggest anthying?

Comment: the precision is to less: for 12.5 you would need numeric(3,1), for 12.345 you would need numeric(5,3).

Answer (score 2):

I can see a couple of things wrong here

You are inserting a record so you do not need a recordset as you are not returning anything.  Use `cmd .Execute` instead of `rs.Open`.

`usrname` is a string so needs to be wrapped in single quotes `'`

Your final code should like more like:

```
Private Sub cmd_update_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection

    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SUVI.suvi.local;InitialCatalog=SUVI;Database=BLS;uid=sa;pwd=123458;"
    con.Open

    strSQL = "insert into duct_test values(" & brdSrNo & ", GetDate(),'" & usrname & "', " & voltMeas1 & ")"

    con.Execute strSQL, , adCmdText

    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

As a side note it is advisable to replace single quotes in any data input by a user with double single quotes.  For example:

`usrname = Replace$(usrname, "'", "''")`

This will help against SQL injection attacks.  Im not saying it will total prevent this but it will help.

If the date you are inserting is always the current date and time you can, as 
nabuchodonossor point out, use `GetDate()`.